# I need the basic java rules like capitalization, brackets, etc. explained to me. When to use what

Tags: java

Im just learning java from youtube. I get a lot of it, but he never explains when and why i use this semicolon, or why scanner is capitalized, but not the word void, Why do i use square brackets instead of curved ones, etc. All very basic day one rules. I think he just assumes I'll catch on eventually, but I would really like to know the whys and hows as i go. thanks

I'm getting why i have to call for the scanner, I understand classes, string names and nextln. But like why is Scanner capitalized and not util? Why are there square brackets next to args. why not round or curly? i kind of understand the curly, but when do we choose to use square or round?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class apples{
  public static void main(String [] args) {

    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
    tuna tunaObject = new tuna ();

    System.out.println ("Enter your name here: ");
    String name = input.nextLine();

    tunaObject.simpleMessage(name);

  } 
}
```

Comment: I recommend looking up _other_ guides in addition to the current one.  You will need more than just a single resource to learn everything.  Or if there is something specific just google it and there is most likely an explanation on stack overflow or elsewhere.

Comment: To help you out some:  Scanner is capitalized because it _is_ a class, classes are capitalized `LikeThisWay`.  `util` is most likely a variable which are not capitalized and instead use `casingLikeThis`.   Square brackets are for Arrays, that is just how Java was made to be.  Round brackets are used in a lot of scenarios and you will just need to learn them all, such as Constructors or in math operations as parenthesis.  In the future please do some self research.

Comment: Search for "java naming conventions" at first

Comment: @Nexevis, It's not like OP needs more then one source. They just need a better source. Any good book should provide answers to these questions.

Comment: @dyukha He is watching a youtube tutorial though, I assume the tutorial does not take the time to explain everything that a book would.  Hence using other sources, such as a book like I recommended.

Comment: @Nexevis, exactly. And this means that youtube tutorial is not a source one should use. No need to get half-knowledge when there are nicely-written more or less complete ones already.

Comment: @dyukha So you expect every youtube tutorial to explain why `Scanner` is capitalized?  There are some things you just don't explain and expect the viewer to do their own research if they have a question about it.  I don't think we can assume how bad the video is from Porshiana's description.

Comment: @Nexevis, no I expect that people shouldn't use youtube at all for learning basics. Just a single source: a book.

Comment: thank you hinotf thats exactly what i needed. The lists I've found using "java naming conventions" are perfect. Now, I cant seem to figure out how i mark yours as the best answer for credit. Could you explain that to me?

Comment: @dyukha Well I hate to break it to you, but in 2019 youtube videos are commonly used to learn things.  It is best to use _all_ available resources, including books _and_ videos.  Disregarding all of youtube to learn something is unnecessary.

Comment: @Nexevis: There's a lot of useful teaching resources on YouTube, but they're best used _together_ with a written tutorial (either a printed book or online) — for basically the same reasons as why schools use both lectures _and_ textbooks even though they basically cover the same material. Anyway, if the OP doesn't want to go out and buy a printed Java book, I'd recommend they [Google for an online Java tutorial](https://www.google.com/search?q=introduction+to+java). Here's [one fairly decent looking one](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaIntroduction/article.html) that I just found.

Comment: @Illmari Karonen Yeah that is literally what I said.  Using multiple resources together.

Answer (score 2):

> Im just learning java from youtube.

You are going to need text sources eventually, even if just to read various documentation. Here is a beginner-friendly place where you might find these answers: https://www.w3schools.com/java/ (extremely beginner friendly, but its reputation for accuracy is not great, so wean yourself off it as you move along) or just Google something like "java naming rules" which will bring you something like this: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html

I will quickly answer your specific questions, but

> I get a lot of it, but he never explains when and why i use this semicolon

Semicolons are used to indicate line termination in Java.

> or why scanner is capitalized

Classes (think boxes full of tools) are capitalized.

> but not the word void,

void is a primitive type. It stands alone and is not a box full of tools. It is similar to int in this regard.

> Why do i use square brackets instead of curved ones, etc.Why are there square brackets next to args.

Square brackets are used to indicate an array. In the case of args, it is so you can send an array of strings into args if you are using the command line.

> why not round or curly?

You use round when you are indicating that it is a method of sorts. Round brackets indicate that a value is being returned to you from the inputs you give it.

{} brackets are to indicate a grouping of code after something like a `for`, `while`, or `if`.

**Basically, each represents some different task. You should pick it up as you go along.**

Comment: Just as a fair warning, while I haven't reviewed W3Schools' Java tutorial in any real detail, [they have a somewhat poor reputation around here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280478/why-not-w3schools-com). They do also have annoyingly good SEO, and often appear as the first Google result, but I'd encourage the OP to look at other tutorials (such as the one I linked to above) as well.

Comment: I've had the problem with w3 myself, which is why I linked the Oracle as well. But it is also quite beginner-friendly relative to more authoritative options, especially when you consider that someone who chooses Youtube over a book (the default choice for Java) is (no offence intended to them) someone for who dense reading is not a preferred way of learning. 

I will add that caveat to the answer though.